# Check if id exist in array field or not using script_fields

Tags: elasticsearch

i like to get a script field if a specific value exist in a array .

Here is my mapping -

```
"mappings": {
    "properties": {
        "field1": {
            "type": "text",
        },
        "field2": {
            "type": "text",
        },
    }
}
```

Here is my example documents -

```
{
    "field1": "hello 1",
    "field2": ["id1","id3"]
}

{
    "field1": "hello 2",
    "field2": ["id2","id3"]
}
{
    "field1": "hello 3",

}
{
    "field1": "mobile 1",
    "field2": ["id1","id4"]
}
```

Here is my search query -

```
{
    "query": {
        "match" : {
            "title": "hello"
        }
    },
    "script_fields":{
        "testField2":{
            "script": {
                "source":"doc['field2'].value ==  params.id ? true : false",
                "params": {
                    "id": "id1"
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

what i want to achieve is to get all those document which has "hello" in their title and add a custom field (testField2) in every doc . the value of that custom field would be True if "field2" contain a specific id ("id1") else False

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `field2` is only mapped as `text`, you **won't** be able to use its field values (via `doc['field2'].value`). You can only use its `_source`:

```json
POST your-index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "field1": "hello"
    }
  },
  "script_fields": {
    "testField2": {
      "script": {
        "source": "params._source.containsKey('field2') ? params._source.field2.contains(params.id) : false",
        "params": {
          "id": "id1"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Note that accessing `_source` is [not as efficient as using the doc values](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/modules-scripting-fields.html#modules-scripting-doc-vals) -- so in short, you were using the right **strategy** but with the wrong **mapping**.

In order to be able to access the doc values, either use the [`keyword` data type](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/keyword.html#keyword-field-type) or set the [`fielddata` parameter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/text.html#fielddata-mapping-param) on your existing `text` field to `true`. I'm going to go with the `keyword` here:

```json
DELETE your-index

PUT your-index
{
  "mappings": {
    "properties": {
      "field1": {
        "type": "text"
      },
      "field2": {
        "type": "keyword"     <--
      }
    }
  }
}
```

After reindexing (which is required after a "mapping breaking change") you can then call:

```json
POST your-index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "field1": "hello"
    }
  },
  "script_fields": {
    "testField2": {
      "script": {
        "source": "doc['field2'].size() != 0 ? doc['field2'].asList().contains(params.id) : false",
        "params": {
          "id": "id1"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Finally, notice the [`.asList()` method](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/current/painless-api-reference-shared-org-elasticsearch-index-fielddata.html#painless-api-reference-shared-ScriptDocValues-Strings). It's needed to convert the doc values which are an instance of the class [`ScriptDocValues.Strings`](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch/7.11.0/org/elasticsearch/index/fielddata/ScriptDocValues.Strings.html) to a consumable `ArrayList` on which you can then call the conventional [`.contains()` method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#contains(java.lang.Object)).

Comment: thank you very much, it worked . previously i tried with keyword & nested mapping, but it wasn't working, probably because i was not using `.asList()` and  `.contain()` method

Comment: @ Joe - ElasticsearchBook.com I just encountered you answer and it works! But I am confused with why `size()` method works on checking if the field exists. I suspect it has to do with internally how the field is mapped. But I couldn't find any resources on this.

Comment: @codeedoc yea it's an [internal method](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.elasticsearch/elasticsearch/7.11.0/org/elasticsearch/index/fielddata/ScriptDocValues.Strings.html#size()) on the doc value instance.